# Generate lambda with Reflection Info

Tags: linq-to-sql, lambda

I have Enitity Type, Name of Primary Key and Guid of Primary Id. I want to get element of such Id in LinqToSql.

```
model.GetTable<T>().Where(t => here equality  );
```

I think I need to generate that Expression myself, but I dont know how :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look forward, and after searching through generated by compiler code, in Reflector I found this creation of lambda.

```
    public static T GetById(Guid id)
    {
        Type entType = typeof(T);

        if (!CheckTable(entType)) {
            throw new TypeLoadException(string.Format(
                "{0} is not Table Entity, has no attribute Table", entType.FullName));
        }

        string property = GetPrimaryKeyName(entType).Name;

        ParameterExpression cs;
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Personal, bool>>(
                Expression.Equal(
                        Expression.Property(
                                cs = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p"), 
                                entType.GetProperty(property).GetGetMethod()
                        ), 
                        Expression.Constant(id), 
                        false, 
                        typeof(Guid).GetMethod("Equals")
                ), new ParameterExpression[] { cs }
        );

        return Connection.Model.GetTable<T>().Single(lambda);
    }
```

The thing what I need, but I have compiler exception:

> Error 5   The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.   D:\Projects\Own\Yabeda\Source\trunk\med\Yabeda.Med.Mvc\Data\Oper.cs 48  20  Yabeda.Med.Mvc

Can't find what this Error means!

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.dynback.com/index.php/2008/11/architecture/database/repository-in-linq-to-sql-getbyid-part/

Result of investigation! Take a look!